# deseason and 'reseason' data

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm doing some work in time series analysis. I'm decomposing a time-series of a moving average as follows

```
  ma<-ts(na.omit(df_summary$ma30),frequency=252)
  decomp=stl(ma,s.window="periodic")
  deseasonal<-seasadj(decomp)
```

I then fit an auto arima model to this, and can make predictions and examine trends.

My question is, how do I 'reseason' the data. If my autoarima and predictions are based off of deseasoned data, how do I translate this back to seasoned data. How do I translate my prediction into a real-world value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the seasonal decomposition method, you can "reseasonalize" by either adding back in (if the decomposition is additive), or multiplying by (if multiplicative) the seasonal component. In the code above, it is additive.

The problem here is that you don't have the seasonal component in the forecast period, and `stats::stl` does not define dynamics for the seasonal component so there's no forecast available for it. The function `forecast::stlf` deals with this by simply copying the last year's seasonal component to cover the forecast period. This may or may not be an appropriate choice depending on how stable your seasonality is. If it isn't, you would probably do better to construct a model that includes seasonality explicitly (like say, a SARIMA model) rather than pre-adjusting before building your model.